# Sure Vs For Sure , the difference

Tags: grammaticality

Could I please borrow your pen ? 
Ans: yeah sure ! 
Vs 
Could I please borrow your pen ? 
Ans: Yeah, for sure!

What's the difference between Sure and For Sure ??!?

I think, sure means - okay 
And For sure- means certainly

But are there more differences? Which one suits better in the given context ?

Comment: The only difference I can think of in your exact context is that ***For sure*** is more likely to be the response from a non-native speaker (but it''s not a *reliable* indicator, to be sure). For me at least, the two-word response ***For sure*** is usually equivalent to ***I agree 100% with what you just said***. But as an Englishman I'd usually just stick with the one-word form anyway. ***For sure*** sounds as "American" to me as ***To be sure*** sounds "Irish".

Comment: Please see [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169576/to-see-vs-seeing#comment340181_169576)

Comment: I think I'll stop here. I hope I have made my point.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can borrow my pen. Conversational.

For sure, you can borrow my pen. Slightly more slangy, also conversational.

For sure has become ubiquitous in American speech. It means the same thing as sure, or yes.