# To see vs Seeing

Tags: infinitives, present-participles

> It felt really nice seeing all the things fall together into place.

Vs

> It felt really nice to see all the things fall together into place.

Is this just an infinite- gerund thing?
Or are the meanings of the two sentences different?

Comment: Subrat, if you ask two or three search engines to conjugate the verb *To see*, which tenses do they show for *seeing* and for *to see* and what does that leave unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

> It felt really nice **seeing** all the things fall together into place.
> It felt really nice **to see** all the things fall together into place.

There is no real difference in meaning or nuance.

However, the usual expression is

> It felt really nice **seeing** things fall into place.
> It felt really nice **to see** things fall into place.

since "***all***" and "***together***" are automatically implied and therefore redundant.