# What does the phrase "that's for sure" mean in this dialogue?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> **A**: Look, I need this vacation; I need a break, from you in particular. I also need to practice my golf and my tennis.
>
> **B**: Well, I don't know about your tennis, but you certainly need to practice your golf. **That's for sure**, ha, ha, ha.

What does "**That's for sure**" mean in this dialogue?

Comment: "That's for sure" is simply an emphatic affirmation that something said earlier is ***definitely** (for sure) **true***. In your case, there's no doubt that A needs to practice his golf (presumably B has just thrashed A in a round of golf, or watched him playing badly).

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Sure Vs For Sure , the difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169364/sure-vs-for-sure-the-difference)

Comment: Source please!!

Comment: It always means the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"That" refers back to the thing that was just said. "That" means "You have to practice your golf".

An "for sure" means "it is certain". So altogher the person is saying "I am certain that you need to practice your golf".  They are *emphatically* repeating the previous sentence.

Person A is saying "I need to leave you, and I need to practice my golf and tennis". This is rather sad and quite rude.

Person B "returns the insult"  by saying "Yes, you really need to practice golf (because your golf is very bad)".

The "ha ha ha" means that person B then tries to pretend that this was a joke and not a real insult.

The impression is that these two people are badly failing to communicate.